# Undefined Index on line 222 of ACL.php

Tags: acl

I received the following message at the top of my Manage ACLs page:

Notice: Undefined index: 5 in CRM_ACL_Page_ACL->browse() (line 222 of /home/ourbase/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/ACL/Page/ACL.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, this was caused by disabling a group of custom fields. Look for a blank spot in the "Which Data" column to show you which one it is. There are two ways to solve this:

Solution 1: Re-enable the custom data group.
or
Solution 2: Remove the offending ACL rule.